# KDE global menu doesn't work in some app. How to override its setting?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, thunderbird, menu, plasma

I use global menu in Kubuntu 17.04 and it doesn't work in some applications like Thunderbird or Skype. The problem is I can't access this menu by no way. I would like to set application-specifically whether the application should use global menu or display menubar in app window. For example in Thuderbird I want to be able to activate this menu using Alt key.
Is it possible? Or is there other solution of the problem?